# How to download steam offfline

Tags: steam

because i will use that in windows 10. So, offline is better.

http://steamcommunity.com/discussions/forum/1/864978762464682676/?

they say here download, install then you can move installed file. But i am on `Ubuntu` now. i cant download to windows directly because it is desktop in home, now i am at school on laptop.

How can i convert that file or what can i do?

Comment: Sorry for this. i dont want to download installer. at home, i have slow internet. now i have schools wifi so i can download windows offline files here instead of going home and clicking install.exe. when clicked installexe, it will downoad again a lot of files. so i need those files here. i am on ubuntu. i can install here but i dont want to put here and if i install here, how can i take to windows because there must be some differencies?

Comment: Ah that makes more sense ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu Steam and Windows Steam are not the same software.

The only way to do that =from the official download= is to install the same OS on the  machine you can download it onto and install Steam on there. Then you can copy the install over to your home machine with the same OS.

Easiest (Muru disagrees :P) method would be:

- install virtualbox
- install Windows in virtualbox
- install steam into Windows
- copy the steam folder + registry key(s) over to your home system.

Comment: Wine would be easier. Steam supports Wine well enough (it's enough for installing games, and Steam on Windows will pick up the downloaded files)

Comment: Here is a howto on wine https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Steam/Wine I hate wine though >:=D

Comment: c/program files/steam file and where are regstry files and how many folders can they be? I dont want to put anything to this laptop so probably i wont use wine, but thanks :) and what about dota 2, it is very long to install. can i also download and move windows from windows?

Comment: Here are some tips on copying: https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=7418-YUBN-8129

Comment: i decided not to download. i will find a friend that is playing it and move his files to my usb.